# Does reassigning a malloc'd string cause memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I have this small function that read words from a file:

```c
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(dictionary,"r");
    //defined LENGTH = 45;
    char *word = malloc(LENGTH + 1);
   
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s[\n]",word) != EOF)
    {
        //do ... thing in here
    }

    free(word);
    return true;
}
```

Will `fscanf` cause memory leak by continuously reassigning `word`?

Comment: `fscanf` will **not** change `word` - it'll change the memory that `word` points to. So no leak here. A leak will happen only when you change `word` (without calling `free(word)` before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this will not cause a memory leak in the way you suggest. `fscanf` does not reassign `word`, but rather modifies its *contents*. You may wish to think of it in terms of: `fscanf` doesn't change `word`, but does change `word[0]`, `word[1]`, etc.

After a call to `fscanf`, `word` will still point to the same *location* in memory (i.e. whatever you got from `malloc`), but the data at that location will be different.